# Monitoring temperature using AWS IoT

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, aws-iot

I've developed an Android app for my dad for monitoring temperature from a specific room.
He wants to be able to see the temperature even when he is not home.

I got working with Amazon IoT and it's pretty great:

1. You publish the temperature to the Amazon IoT server
2. You forward the result to your app

But I also want a device like this using the same app, so how can I make my android app identify with a specific device? I don't want a login mechanism, I just want to give my dad a digital key and based on that my app will identify which devices are his and subscribe only to that.

What am I thinking is this: generate a key that will be stored on the raspberry and when you send a message to the server append that ID. Similar when using the app it will ask for the key which you should get from a admin.

Is this a good way? or do you now an easier alternative through Amazon IoT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provision an IoT thing. For your purpose, you can just do a one off.
In your case, use the client id for your dad's device in the SQL where clause of the IoT rule.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-clientid

Another idea is to change the topic that is published. Perhaps temperature/dadsRoom and use that in the IoT rule. This would probably be the easiest to merge later if you want a report of all rooms.